# Download an excel file generated from a query to the database

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jax-rs

I am looking for the possibility of creating an excel file from a query that a user may generate on our database, so that the user can download it.

Currently we have results displaying to the GUI, but I am wondering what is the best way to create the excel file with the data returned. I'm using a MySQL DB, java JAxRS, JavaScript & html5.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Did you mean a comma-separated values (CSV) file?

Comment: use apache POI to write the excel file , once you get the result set from the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As javadev mentioned, Apache POI is one of the best approach I would also suggest. [Here is an example code](http://javaprogramming.language-tutorial.com/2012/10/writing-resultset-to-excel-file.html) that suits your requirement. Hope this would help.

Comment: This seems to be pretty much what i need - marking this as the answer, Cheers

Comment: One more thing, iv set this up in my webapp but i cant figure out what i should put in for:   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); Im using JBOSS and mySQL

Comment: You should specify the JDBC Driver implementation class using Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); This class will be available inside a Jar file in your My SQL installation which should be set to your classpath. Hope this would help. [http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/]

Comment: Thanks - that link helped - i just added the mysql dependency in my pom.xml - cheers

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommand to use [Apache POI API](http://poi.apache.org/)

[Here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-to-an-excel-file-using-poi.html) is a good tutorial to start.

Comment: Cheers, that is what i use to get the data into the database - so i can apply this to reverse engineer..

Comment: Yes, POI can either be used to read Excel files or to write new ones!